# I want to add a hyperlink field in ASP.Net to a gridview control or the data behind it

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, hyperlink, datatable

I am dynamically generating a gridview control on the fly.  I need to set one of the fields to a hyperlink, and set the value to a dynamic URL.  My code so far is:

```
 Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
 Dim strCol As String = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(5).Text.ToString
 Dim files As String() = IO.Directory.GetFiles(("z:/medadmissions/ap/entering2014/" & strCol & "/"))
 Dim strURL As String
 Dim HLF As HyperLinkField

 Dim dt As New DataTable
 dt.Columns.Add("Name")
 dt.Columns.Add("Document Type")

 For Each f As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles("z:\medadmissions\ap\entering2014\" & strCol & "\")
    Dim r As DataRow = dt.NewRow
    r("Name") = IO.Path.GetFileName(f)

    strURL = "z:\medadmissions\ap\entering2014\" & strCol & "\" & r("Name").ToString

    'Want to add this column as a Hyperlink column with strURL
    r("Document Type") = "Type"

 Next f



 Dim gv As New GridView
 gvFiles.DataSource = dt
 gvFiles.DataBind()


 End Sub
```

I imagine there is an easy way to tell the column labeled "Document Type" that I am wanting it to pass a hyperlink.  What am I missing?

Thank you,

David

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach? Are you recieving errors?

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3f53e654-3de3-4a88-8e91-6bcd6bf2d3d1/hyperlink-in-databound-datagridview

go read on that link a bit, you should find something there.

You can also try to put an html encoded string in there. but thats bad practice and I'm still learning these things.

hope this helped